# Get the user name based on the id in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, models, relationships

i'm trying to show a first name  of a user, but i just have a user's id.

My relationships are:

```
//TypeCost
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }



  //User
        public function type_cost()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('TypeCost', 'type_cost_user');
        }
```

This line show me User's Id, but I need the name.

```
<td>{{ $type_cost->user_id}}<br>
```

I hope your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the TypeCost model hasMany relationship returns an object of type Collection, you have 2 options, using first or tour the object using foreach, also in the User model the relationship belongsToMany returns an object of type Collection, here you can see an example:

```
{{ $type_cost->user->first()->username }}
```

or

```
@foreach($type_cost->user as $user)
   {{ $user->username }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's ok, i can't speak/write in english jajaja

Comment: if you need to know more about relationships in Laravel check this link http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 4):

This will give a user's name if you have the ID saved in `$type_cost->user_id`:

`User::find($type_cost->user_id)->name`

Answer (score -2):

You should use whatever field name you have used to store the users name.

E.G.

```
{{$type_cost->user->username}}
```

Comment: `$type_cost->user()` will return you a `Relation` instance and no actual data, so you can't access `username` on it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have this error: ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) 
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$first_name (View: /var/www/control_telefonico/app/views/type_costs/index.blade.php)

Comment: @MiguelMarroquin Take out the `()`. I've revised the answer.

Comment: Also this still won't work because `user` is a `hasMany` relation so you'll get a collection and no model.